# Counting problem, tiling rectangle with two types right isosceles triangle

Tags: co.combinatorics, recurrences, tiling

How many ways are there to tile a rectangle of size $m\times n$ with two types of isosceles triangle, type 1 having area $\frac{1}{2}$ and type 2 having area 1?

I know with only type 1 there are $2^{mn}$ ways, but I don't have any idea how to continue.